# data table subset last row by group (retain order)

Tags: r, data.table, subset

Have:

```
> aDT <- data.table(ID = c(3,3,2,2,2,3), colA = c(5,5,4,4,4,5), colC = c(1:6))
> aDT
   ID colA colC
1:  3    5    1
2:  3    5    2
3:  2    4    3
4:  2    4    4
5:  2    4    5
6:  3    5    6
```

Need:

```
> aDT <- data.table(ID = c(3,2,3), colA = c(5,4,5), colC = c(2,5,6))
> aDT
   ID colA colC
1:  3    5    2
2:  2    4    5
3:  3    5    6
```

Tried:

```
> aDT[, .SD[.N], by = list(ID,colA)]
   ID colA colC
1:  3    5    6
2:  2    4    5
```

As you can see, the result's not really what I need. How to fix it?
(btw, I would like to retain the same order)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not really grouping by `ID` and `colA` but by the consecutive chunks, for which you can use `rleid` for this purpose:

```
aDT[aDT[, .I[.N], rleid(ID, colA)]$V1]

#   ID colA colC
#1:  3    5    2
#2:  2    4    5
#3:  3    5    6
```

`.I[.N]` extracts the global row number of the last row for each group:

```
aDT[, .I[.N], rleid(ID, colA)]

#   rleid V1               
#1:     1  2
#2:     2  5
#3:     3  6      there are three groups in total, the row numbers of last rows are 2,5,6
```

then use the row numbers to subset the original data table.